# SQL Server: how do I know if I have lost or corrupt data after an automatic recovery?

Tags: sql-server

My SQL Server 2000 logs show that the server performed an automatic recovery on several of our databases. The logs do not mention any errors found. Could I have corrupt or lost data?

Comment: On start up? This always happens. On when DB is brought "online"

Comment: @Mitch Wheat, you are right, I just voted to migrate my own question ;)

Comment: @gbn, thanks, I didn't know it did that at startup, answers my question.  This is what happens when a programmer is force to moonlight as a DBA.  Put that in an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens automatically when

- SQL Server starts
- you attach a DB
- bringing a database it online
- ...

Nothing to worry about.